# Insert a image in MediumBLOB column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a record in mysql database using the following query, but getting the #1064-sql syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO RESOURCES(ID, NAME, RESTYPE, CONTENT) VALUES('4', 'Printer.TicketTotal', 0, LOAD_FILE('/home/anand/Openbravo-POS/main/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/templates/Printer.TicketTotal.xml));

INSERT INTO RESOURCES(ID, NAME, RESTYPE, CONTENT) VALUES('4', 'Printer.TicketTotal', 0, $FILE{/home/anand/Openbravo-POS/main/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/templates/Printer.TicketTotal.xml});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `'` at the end of file name -

```
INSERT INTO RESOURCES(ID, NAME, RESTYPE, CONTENT) VALUES
  ('4',
  'Printer.TicketTotal',
  0, 
  LOAD_FILE('/home/anand/Openbravo-POS/main/src-pos/com/openbravo/pos/templates/Printer.TicketTotal.xml'));
```

Comment: Is, LOAD_FILE similar to upload a file for a column from phpmyadmin?

Comment: The LOAD_FILE is a MySQL function. It is possible that phpmyadmin uses it.

Comment: but when i try that from phpmyadmin,  the column (MediumBLOB) takes  NULL value.

Comment: That may because of privileges, read the documentation about this function. In your case - #1064 - you had the error.